# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException for SimpleDate class

Tags: java

This program is for converting ISO dates (ex: 2014-02-15) and being able to convert this into "February 15 2014" but I am having trouble with the constructor, here is what I have so far:

```
public SimpleDate(String isoDate)
{
        // test print
       System.out.println(isoDate);

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(isoDate);
       sc.useDelimiter("­-");

       this.year = sc.nextInt();
       this.month = sc.nextInt();
       this.day = sc.nextInt();

       System.out.println(year);
}//constructor
```

I have a test in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

       SimpleDate date = new SimpleDate("2014-12-12");

}//main
```

When running the code as it is I get the test print in the constructor to execute but I get this error soon afterwards:

```
Test Print: 2014-12-12
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at SimpleDate.<init>(SimpleDate.java:19)
at SimpleDate.main(SimpleDate.java:68)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `isoDate.split("-");`, then call `Integer.parseInt` on each of the resulting elements?  Alternatively, you could use a `SimpleDateFormat` object to parse `isoDate`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out =] but it was just a pasting error from copying and pasting the code into here. I corrected it tho and its still giving me the "
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" error.

Comment: Try to erase and rewrite the `-`. When i copy-paste this to my IDE, it gives me the error you said. If I rewrite that part, it works, I don't know why. Maybe some weird character or something.

Comment: So, instead of messing round with a `Scanner`, why don't you just use `isoDate.split("-");` as I suggested earlier?

Comment: actually erasing and rewriting worked thank you! And thank you David for your input the .split worked as well! however just to be on the safe side I'm going to keep using the scanner object on account of my instructor gave us that piece of code to work off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
sc.useDelimiter("­-");
```

with

```
sc.useDelimiter("­\n|-");
```

as `Scanner` requires you to press Enter at the end.

Comment: actually my instructor gave us that piece of code to work with and it turns out when I copied and pasted it into my code it didn't recognize the hyphen and all that was missing was for me to rewrite it XD but your way also got it working! thanks =]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of the "standard" date classes to perform this simple conversion. This code should help you do so:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class SimpleDate {
private Date date ;
public SimpleDate(String isoDate) throws ParseException
{
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(isoDate);
}   
private String convert() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d yyyy").format(date);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
     System.out.println( new SimpleDate("2014-02-15").convert());          

}//main
```

}

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this.  I think the literal in the `convert` method needs to have `d` instead of `MM` in the middle though.

Comment: Exactly. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As your delimiter is `""`, the scanner scans your input and returns `2014-12-12` - you clearly want to split the string at `-`.

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a pasting issue =/ It's now fixed...but I'm still stuck =[

Comment: Then please edit your post to reflect the new question you are having.

Comment: the question is the same, it was just a pasting error I missed. Its still giving me the same issue because the hyphen was always in the original code

Comment: funny that that very hyphen was the reason it wasn't working to begin with XD